# Initialising an object outside of the main method java

Tags: java, oop, object

I’m trying the code below but It doesn’t let me to initialise the socket object outside of the main method.
Can someone please explain the problem to me?

```
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

public class Server
{
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Server server = new Server();
    //server.socket = new DatagramSocket(); this is the suggested and working way

    }
} 

/*The error is : error: unreported exception SocketException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();*/
```

Why don’t I get the error when I initialise other objects outside main method?
Should all the objects be initialised inside main method?

**Update:**
What counfused me is the answer to [this question](https://coderanch.com/t/502516/java/class-instantiated-main) : 
“Generally, you don't create objects outside of METHODS - main or otherwise. So you CAN create objects outside of main, but inside some OTHER method.”

Why is that a problem?

Comment: Because the main method is static, if you want to use the Datagram socket in that context but created outside it must also be static.

`static DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket()`

Comment: error: unreported exception SocketException; must be caught or declared to be thrown.  

  static DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();

Comment: But if I use server.socket = new DatagramSocket(); it won’t show the error even though I don’t use try catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the DatagramSocket constructor throws a SocketException so that Throwable must be caught. You cannot catch a Throwable as a class member.

Comment: So is the problem only with this type of object? Can you initialise other objects outside the main method and is it preferable to do the initialisation inside the main method or outside of it?

Comment: The main method is just the entry point to the application. You definitely do not have to declare the object in the main method.

Comment: I was looking at this question https://coderanch.com/t/502516/java/class-instantiated-mai and you can see the first answer says “ Generally, you don't create objects outside of METHODS - main or otherwise. So you CAN create objects outside of main, but inside some OTHER method.” so why is that?

Comment: That response was from 9 years ago, and it was specifically relating to a person who was creating a member in a class and then modifying the member in the class, which is not permitted.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer rightly points out, you need to handle the exception. You can do something like this:

```
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

public class Server
{
    DatagramSocket socket = newDatagramSocket();

    private static DatagramSocket newDatagramSocket() {
        try {
            return new DatagramSocket();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        //server.socket = new DatagramSocket(); this is the suggested and working way

    }
}
```

In this case it's handled by stack trace + exit with error, but one other alternative might be `null` instead.